# Laravel: Undefined variable: anmeldung (View: /Users/rotschaedl/nost1/resources/views/uebersicht.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Code in the Controller.

```
public static function allean(){
        $anmeldung=DB::table('anmeldung')->select('*')->get();
        echo $anmeldung;
        return view('uebersicht', compact('anmeldung'));
}
```

This is m Code in the View.

```
<?php
MainController::allean();
?>    

@if(null!==session('lehrer'))
            @foreach($anmeldung as $row)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="central">1</th>
                    <td class="central"> $row['vorname']}} {{$row['nachname']}} </td>
                    <td class="central">0000000</td>
                    <td class="central">AAA</td>
                    <td class="central">ok</td>
                    <td class="central">aaaaa</td>
                    <td class="central">Mathe</td>
                    <td class="central">ooooo</td>
                    <td class="central">asd </td>
                    <td class="central">12.10.2018</td>
                    <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
                    <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

And i get that error on the site.

> Undefined variable: anmeldung (View:
>   /Users/user/project/resources/views/uebersicht.blade.php)

Comment: Hi, can you try `dd($anmeldung)` in function and check its value.

Comment: if $anmeldung not empty just remove `echo $anmeldung` from the function and it will work

Comment: Check out my answer, you missing {{ }}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should modify your view like this:

**Controller**

```
public static function allean(){
        $anmeldung = DB::table('anmeldung')->select('*')->get();
        return $anmeldung;
}
```

**View**

```
@if(null!==session('lehrer'))
    @foreach(App\MainController::allean() as $row)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="central">1</th>
            <td class="central"> $row['vorname']}} {{$row['nachname']}} </td>
            <td class="central">0000000</td>
            <td class="central">AAA</td>
            <td class="central">ok</td>
            <td class="central">aaaaa</td>
            <td class="central">Mathe</td>
            <td class="central">ooooo</td>
            <td class="central">asd </td>
            <td class="central">12.10.2018</td>
            <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
            <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: thank you that worked for my project but you have to change $row['vorname‘] to $row->vorname

Answer (score 1):

Try using a key value pair :

```
public static function allean(){
        $anmeldung=DB::table('anmeldung')->select('*')->get();
        echo $anmeldung;
        return view('uebersicht', ['anmeldung'=>$anmeldung]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

Add if condition before foreach   `@if(!empty($anmeldung))@endif`

```
@if(null!==session('lehrer'))
            @if(!empty($anmeldung))
            @foreach($anmeldung as $row)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="central">1</th>
                    <td class="central"> $row['vorname']}} {{$row['nachname']}} </td>
                    <td class="central">0000000</td>
                    <td class="central">AAA</td>
                    <td class="central">ok</td>
                    <td class="central">aaaaa</td>
                    <td class="central">Mathe</td>
                    <td class="central">ooooo</td>
                    <td class="central">asd </td>
                    <td class="central">12.10.2018</td>
                    <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
                    <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
@endif
        @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `{{` near `<td class="central">  $row['vorname']}} {{$row['nachname']}} </td>`

You can try this code :

```
public static function allean(){
        $anmeldung=DB::table('anmeldung')->select('*')->get();
        //var_dump($anmeldung);
        return View::make('uebersicht')->with(compact('anmeldung'));
}
```

You should modify your view like this:

```
@if(null!==session('lehrer'))
        @foreach($anmeldung as $row)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="central">1</th>
                <td class="central"> {{ $row['vorname']}} {{$row['nachname']}} </td>
                <td class="central">0000000</td>
                <td class="central">AAA</td>
                <td class="central">ok</td>
                <td class="central">aaaaa</td>
                <td class="central">Mathe</td>
                <td class="central">ooooo</td>
                <td class="central">asd </td>
                <td class="central">12.10.2018</td>
                <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
                <td class="central">{{Form::checkbox('', '')}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Comment: @rotschaedl which error ? For "{" or variable missing?

Comment: for undefined variable

Comment: @rotschaedl what you get in var_dump($anmeldung) or dd($anmeldung) withing the function?

Comment: just fixed the problem with the answer from Davide Casiraghi but thank you anyway!